# how to retrive list from inner class

Tags: inner-class

class code:

```
public list<innerclass> inclass= new list<innerclass>();
 public class innerclass
    {
        public string accountid{get; set;}
        public string accountname{get; set;}
        public set<string> Rid=new set<string>();
        public set<string> Rvalue =new set<string>();
        public innerclass(string Accountid1,String accountname1,list<string> Rid1,list<string> Rvalue1)
        {
            if(Rid.containsAll(Rid1)==False)
            {
                accountname=accountname1;
                Accountid=Accountid1;
                Rid.addall(Rid1);
                rvalue.addAll(rvalue1);
            }
        } 
    }
```

vf page code:

```
<apex:column headerValue="name" value="{!av.accountname}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!av.Rid}"/> 

 </apex:PageBlockTable>
```

But it gives

> error:Error   Error: Unknown property 'checkbox4.innerclass.rid'

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

- `Rid` is a collection (a `Set`) not a single value so that is a design problem; hard to see what your `innerclass` aims to do i.e. why you want multiple values there
- To make it accessible in Visualforce it needs to be exposed as an [Apex Property](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_properties.htm) just as `accountname` is exposed

Best you edit your question to explain more what you are trying to do to get a more definite answer.

**PS**

If you make `Rid` a property you can output the multiple values using e.g.:

```
<apex:column>
    <apex:repeat value="{!av.Rid}" var="item">
        {!item}<br/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:column>
```

Comment: I want only set of rid to page

Comment: Is it possible or not???

Comment: @satishh I've added a PS.

Comment: thanks @ps but Rid is a set which is present inside inner class

Comment: @satishh Yes I realise that and have given you all the information I can. If its not enough wait for a better answer.